# Get Category ID in url

Tags: php

I can not find nothing on internet about getting category id  in url, so I post here.

I want an url like this : `localhost/index.php&cat=1` , when I press submit button.

I use this code:

```
<form method="post" id="categories">
<select name="category">
<option value="">Select a category</option>
<?php
getCats();
?>
</select>
<button type="submit" form="categories" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and `getcats`:

```
function getCats(){
global $con;
$get_cats = "select * from category";
$run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);
while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
    $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
    $cat_name = $row_cats['name'];
echo "<li><button><a href='index.php?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_name</a></button></li>";
}
}
```

It's possible to use `form action=` in this case?

Comment: method `method="post"` to method="get"...

Comment: Please learn how to code first. you are echoing <li> without <ul> tag. and echoing <li> In <select> tag instead of <option>

Comment: @devpro : Thats not working because of <a> tag

Comment: why u need select box here? u can choose one select or ul li

Answer (score 0):

you most remind these two tip:

1) query string only on GET method are accessible.

2) query string starts whit **?** and if parameters are more than one seperate with **&**

in your question you use this:

> localhost/index.php&cat=1

but it must be:

> localhost/index.php?cat=1&name=blah

if you use this tips now you can get data in your php code like this:

```
$cat = $_GET["cat"]; //will be '1'
$name = $_GET["name"]; // will be 'blah'
```